# nagios installation problem

Tags: nagios

i am following the below url for nagios installation http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/05/nagios-30-jumpstart-guide-for-red-hat-overview-installation-and-configuration/#more-5

When i try to configure web interface.

```
# make install-webconf
```

I am getting the below error

> make: *** No rule to make target
>   `install-webconf'.  Stop.

I have installed Apache and running fine, but can't find the conf.d directory

```
# service httpd status
httpd (pid  6975) is running...
```

can anyone help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in the same directory as the Makefile. If you must run a makefile from somewhere else, do it like so:

> make -f /path/to/Makefile install-webconf

If you DO have the Makefile next to you - make sure you're actually in the right directory - sometimes subdirs in a source tarball have their own. If this is not the case, then most likely your instructions are "outdated" or there's something "wrong" with the tarball you downloaded. Given that those instructions are 3 years old, this could be the case...

Current documentation for nagios can be [found here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/toc.html).

Comment: #mkdir conf.d

# /etc/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 28 00:34 build -> /var/www/build
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Apr 29 15:11 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 29 16:37 conf.d

# make -f /etc/httpd/conf.d/makefile install-webconf
make: /etc/httpd/conf.d/makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/etc/httpd/conf.d/makefile'.  Stop.

# make -f /etc/httpd/conf.d/install-webconf
make: /etc/httpd/conf.d/install-webconf: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/etc/httpd/conf.d/install-webconf'.  Stop.

Comment: Please note the capital "M" in Makefile - that is not a typo.